# hyperkube proxy, kubelet can't find iptables chain, rkt run --net=host

Tags: docker, kubernetes, iptables, rkt, kubelet

My kubelet complains:

> E1201 09:00:12.562610   28747 kubelet_network.go:365] Failed to ensure
>   rule to drop packet marked by KUBE-MARK-DROP in filter chain
>   KUBE-FIREWALL: error appending rule: exit status 1: iptables: No
>   chain/target/match by that name.

This is usually happens when you forget to 'rkt run' with --net-host, but I have not.

> export RKT_OPTS="--volume var-log,kind=host,source=/var/log \
>   --mount volume=var-log,target=/var/log \   --volume dns,kind=host,source=/etc/resolv.conf \   --mount
>   volume=dns,target=/etc/resolv.conf --net=host"

The following confirms my kube-proxy (started by kubelet) is in the same namespace as the host that owns the iptables chains:

```
root@i8:/etc# d exec -it 738 readlink /proc/self/ns/net
net:[4026531963]

root@i8:/etc# readlink /proc/self/ns/net
net:[4026531963]

root@i8:/etc# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                           NAMES
738ed14ec802        quay.io/coreos/hyperkube:v1.4.6_coreos.0   "/hyperkube proxy --m"   44 minutes ago      Up 44 minutes                                       k8s_kube-proxy.c445d412_kube-proxy-192.168.101.128_kube-system_438e3d01f328e73a199c6c0ed1f92053_10197c34
```

The proxy similarly complains "No chain/target/match by that name".

I have also verified the iptables chain:

```
# Completed on Thu Dec  1 01:07:11 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Dec  1 01:07:11 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [4852:1419411]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [5612:5965118]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION - [0:0]
:KUBE-FIREWALL - [0:0]
:KUBE-SERVICES - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
-A KUBE-FIREWALL -m mark --mark 0x8000/0x8000 -j DROP
COMMIT
```

This satisfies the complaint in the error message (I think) and matches the filter chain on a problem-free coreos worker (different machine I compared with).

The problem worker is Debian Jessie running docker 1.12.3 and rkt 1.18.0

Both the good worker and problem worker are running the same version of iptables, 1.4.21

KUBELET_VERSION=v1.4.6_coreos.0

The symptom is that kubernetes on the problem worker does not install any iptables rules, like KUBE-NODEPORTS, and so this worker cannot listen for NodePort services.  I think it's because of the above.

The problem worker has no problem running pods that the Master Node schedules.

Pods on the problem worker are serving requests OK from a proxy running on a different (coreos) worker.

I'm using flannel for networking.

If anyone was wondering, I need to get kubernetes working on Debian (yeah, it's a long story)

What else can I do to isolate what seems to be kubelet not seeing the host's iptables?

Answer (score 0):

After much fault isolation, I've found the cause and solution.

In my case, I'm running a custom kernel pkg (linux-image), which was missing several kernel modules related to iptables. So when kubelet tried to append iptables rules that contained a comment, it errored because xt_comment wasn't loaded.

These are the modules I was missing:  ipt_REJECT, nf_conntrack_netlink, nf_reject_ipv4, sch_fq_codel (maybe not required), xt_comment, xt_mark, xt_recent, xt_statistic

To get a complete list of modules that I likely needed, I logged into a CoreOS kubernetes worker and looked at its `lsmod`. Then just compared that list to my "problem" machine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on a gentoo box with a custom kernel configuration whilst running k8s using rancher's k3d 1.3.1. Rebuilding the kernel with all the sane iptables + xt_comment solved this issue for me.